# Update a previous document in the solr using Java

Tags: java, solr

I am new to the `Java with Solr` . Here, I am adding a document in solr and then I do some changes and then I want to update that whole document.But Right now when ever I do this, a new document is getting created in solr with a new ID. Can any one please explain me how to do this ?

```
server.add(doc);
server.commit();
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You must define a unique key in your schema.

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

See: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#The_Unique_Key_Field

> The Unique Key Field
>
> The  declaration can be used to inform Solr that there is a
>   field in your index which should be unique for all documents. If a
>   document is added that contains the same value for this field as an
>   existing document, the old document will be deleted.